# Before and after event handlers in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to watch objects so that a block or lamba is run before and/or after calls on specific methods for that object? For example, something like this:

```
watch(lionel, :say_you, :before) do
    puts '[before say_you]'
end

lionel.say_you()
# outputs [before say_you]
```

An important part of my requirement is that I don't want to monkey patch the object at all. There should be no changes to the object. I just want to watch it, not change it (Heisenberg would be proud).

I've written a module that sort of does what I describe. Unfortunately, it has some bad side-effects: it slows down the system and never cleans up its hash of object ids. So I wouldn't use it in production, but it shows the concept of watching an object without monkey patching it.

```
# watcher module
# (Adrian is one of The Watchmen)
module Adrian
   @registry = {}
   EVENT_IDS = {:before => :call, :after => :return}

   # watch
   def self.watch(obj, method, event_id, &handler)
      # get event type
      event = EVENT_IDS[event_id]
      event or raise 'unknown-event: unknown event param'

      # get object id
      obj_id = obj.object_id

      # store handler
      @registry[obj_id] ||= {}
      @registry[obj_id][method] ||= {}
      @registry[obj_id][method][event] ||= []
      @registry[obj_id][method][event].push(handler)
   end

   # trace
   TracePoint.trace(:call, :return) do |tp|
      # get watched object or return
      if handlers = @registry[tp.binding.receiver.object_id]
         handle tp, handlers
      end
   end

   # handle
   def self.handle(tp, handlers)
      # $tm.hrm

      # if this method is watched
      callee = handlers[tp.callee_id]
      callee or return

      # get blocks
      blocks = callee[tp.event]
      blocks or return

      # loop through series
      blocks.each do |block|
         block.call
      end
   end
end

# Lionel class
class Lionel
   def say_you
      puts 'you'
   end

   def say_me
      puts 'me'
   end
end

# instance
lionel = Lionel.new()

# before
Adrian.watch(lionel, :say_you, :before) do
   puts '[before say_you]'
end

# after
Adrian.watch(lionel, :say_me, :after) do
   puts '[after say_me]'
end

# call method
lionel.say_you
lionel.say_me
```

That outputs:

```
[before say_you]
you
me
[after say_me]
```

Comment: Why not patch the object? It's how this type of instrumentation is usually done. This, or decorators (but decorating an object will generate a new object, which may not be what you want).

Comment: Calling `watch(lionel)` actually calls the method, you may want: `watch(:lionel, ...)` which will direct it to manipulate that method by redefining it and aliasing it.

Comment: @tadman: `lionel` is a local var, though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oh, in that case this really isn't practical. You can't wrap on a reference to a variable without some dark magic.

Comment: @tadman: I'd use some MP magic, yes. But Mike has devised a tracepoint-based solution, patchless. With its own drawbacks.

Comment: Instinctively I'd think something like `lionel = watch(lionel, ...)` is preferable to this more *magical* approach. When the variable falls out of scope, so will the watcher and there's no GC issues.

Comment: Without getting into too much detail right now, I'm developing a new object oriented paradigm called XT classes. The idea is that you can add properties, methods, and events to any object without modifying the object itself. You can even do that to core objects like strings and integers. The objects retain their XT classes even when the variables that hold them go out of scope. But for my concept to work, people need to be clear that their objects themselves are not changing at all.

Comment: I see what appears to be working code, and interesting comments. Is this a question on how to refactor or improve your code?  Can anyone giving comments provide actual answer examples if you have any?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution making use of the singleton class for the object you want to watch.  I am not sure it's *good* solution, but it might be at least *interesting*.

The watch method takes, and object, a method name, and an order parameter along with a block.  The order parameter specifies when you want to run the block, ie before, after or around the watched method.

The watch method saves the original instance method, then defines a singleton method with the same name as the original method on the object. The singleton method calls the passed block at the time or times specified by the order parameter. The singleton method also calls with the original instance method bound to the object at the appropriate time.

Perhaps there is a better way to call an instance method from with in a singleton method, but I have not found one.  I am also not sure how this would work with various argument types, ie keyword args, etc.

Here is the watch method.

```
def watch(obj,method_name,order,&block)
    inst_method = obj.class.instance_method(method_name)
    obj.define_singleton_method(method_name) do |*args|
        block.call if [:before,:around].include?(order)
        inst_method.bind(self).call(*args) 
        block.call if [:after,:around].include?(order)
    end    
end
```

Usage examples:

```
class Foo 
    def initialize(type)
        @type = type
    end

    def i_method(arg)
        puts "#{@type} instance method called with arg = #{arg}"
    end
end

watched_inst = Foo.new("watched")
unwatched_inst = Foo.new("unwatched") 

watch(watched_inst,:i_method,:before) do 
   puts "do before"
end

watched_inst.i_method("foo")
unwatched_inst.i_method("bar")
watched_inst.i_method("foo_bar")

watch(watched_inst,:i_method,:after) do 
   puts "do after"
end

watched_inst.i_method("hello")

watch(watched_inst,:i_method,:around) do 
   puts "do around"
end

watched_inst.i_method("hello")

unwatched_inst.i_method("foo")
```

output:

```
do before
watched instance method called with arg = foo
unwatched instance method called with arg = bar
do before
watched instance method called with arg = foo_bar
watched instance method called with arg = hello
do after
do around
watched instance method called with arg = hello
do around
unwatched instance method called with arg = foo
```

Comment: Very interesting! It's not quite what I wanted but it's very close. It would probably work for now. Thanks!